# openssl pbkdf2 and perl

Tags: perl, openssl, pbkdf2

I have created some perl scripts to encrypt and decrypt documents. I do this successfully using openssl 3.0.2. I use openssl enc and -pbkdf2 for greater security keeping my 'password' separate from the encoded data. Unfortunately, I don't have access to linux wherever I am so have tried to use perl module Crypt::CBC but only to decrypt what I have already encrypted with openssl (as I can use Strawberry perl on a MS machine).
I want to know if this is even possible, given I don't know exactly how openssl has derived key, vi, salt etc from the plain text password.
I keep getting error:

```
The key must be 128, 192 or 256 bits long at /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Crypt/CBC.pm line 692.
```

The cipher I am using is aes-256-cbc.
This is probably a stupid question (but I am a newb at this).

I expected that, having the password/passphrase used to encrypt, I would be able to decrypt.
I am using:

```
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
     -key    => $password,
     -cipher => "Crypt::OpenSSL::AES",
     -pbkdf  => 'pbkdf2',
);
```

Comment: A minimal, complete working example would be very helpful.

Comment: Generate a Passphrase
system("openssl rand -out secret.test 500");
Encrypt:
system("openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in $plaintext -out $encrypted.enc -pass file:$secret.test");
Decrypt (successfully) plaintext:
system("openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in $encrypted.enc -pass file:$secret.test");
I fail to decrypt $encrypted.enc with:
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        {
                'key'    => $secret.test,
                'cipher' => 'Cipher::AES',
                'pbkdf'  => 'pbkdf2',
        }
);
$decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);

Comment: Edit your question to include your example.